# Python socket connection not working over Local Network

Tags: python, sockets, networking, lan, wan

I'm trying to get two computers (my PC and my laptop) to communicate over the Local Network using the Socket module in python.

This is the Server side code running on my PC (connected via LAN):

```
import socket

HOST = '192.168.1.3' #local PC IP
print(HOST)
PORT = 8080        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print(data)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

And this is the Client side code, running on my Laptop (connected over WiFi):

```
import socket


TCP_IP = '192.168.1.3'
TCP_PORT = 8080
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

MESSAGE = b"Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

s.send(MESSAGE)

data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

s.close()

print("received data:", data)
```

The thing is: when I execute both codes, the Server side stays idle waiting for a connection and the Client side, after a while stops and returns the following timeout error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\client.py", line 13, in <module>
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I can't understand why it won't connect from another device in the same network while it works perfectly if I execute the Client code on the same machine as the Server, even if when I run `netstat -an` in the CMD I can see the computer listening on that port:

```
TCP    192.168.1.3:8080       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I tough it had something to do with the port forwarding so I tried playing around with it but I'm having troubles with that too (the ports seem to remain closed).

I really don't know what to do next, if you have some advice or know something else I could try please reply.

Comment: Check connectivity from client to server (ping). If it is ok then the issue can be firewall rules at the server. What OS is it? Is there a firewall configured?

Comment: Client connectivity works fine, I can get a response from google and even my wireless printer. Both the server and client run on Windows 10 machines and the only firewall I can think of is the standard one on the router

Answer (score 2):

It actually was a firewall problem, I just needed to disable the windows defender firewall for the local network and now everything is working fine

Comment: I seem to still be running into the same error, even when I disable windows stuff.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10, I had to open the port I was using for the socket, and it worked for me.

Here is a [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-open-port-in-windows-10-firewall/f38f67c8-23e8-459d-9552-c1b94cca579a) to the instructions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You're listening and connecting to the same IP - you need to listen to the client's IP(or just any IP with the correct port number) on the server and connect to the server's IP on the client.

For example, if the client's IP is 1.2.3.4 and the server's is 1.2.3.5, then

```py
# server side
s.bind(('1.2.3.4', 8080))  # CLIENT_IP = '1.2.3.4'; PORT = 8080

# can also be s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8080)) if you want multiple clients to connect.
```

```py
# client side
s.connect(('1.2.3.5', 8080))  # SERVER_IP = '1.2.3.5'; PORT = 8080
```

Comment: If I try this on the server side i get: OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context, if I leave the IP empty or put the zeros I get the usual timeout on the client .

Comment: Why should the server know client's IP? What if there are multiple clients?